# Stuck in a forever loop

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

I am trying to make the below code loop through all the pdfs in my directory, extract the text from these pdfs and print them in once block using the code below.
I am currently getting stuck in a forever while loop. Additionally how can my code be modified to perform the same function using the for loop?

```
import glob
import PyPDF2
pdfs=glob.glob("/private/babik/*.pdf")
file_name = "Announcement"
index = 0
while index<=len(pdfs):
 pdfFileObj = open(str(pdfs[index]), 'rb')
# creating a pdf reader objecct
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj,strict=False)
print(pdfReader.numPages)
pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
print(pageObj.extractText())
pdfFileObj.close()
index+=1
```

Comment: Are you sure? You could add `print("index", index)` to the top of the list. It should go from 0 to one less than the number of pdfs, then the while should terminate.

Comment: Can you click on 'edited' (to the left of your stackoverflow ID)? See revision 2 of your question for the right code formatting (spaces) getting you out of a forever loop.

Comment: After the rollback, the problem is clear that `index+=1` is outside of the while loop. Use 4 spaces for indent and include whitespace in `index += 1` and etc... The (PEP8 style guide)[https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/] helps keep code readable. The spacing helps spot block indentation errors.

Comment: thanks for the advice on formatting- will keep that i mind

Answer (score 1):

In Python spaces at the beginning of line impact the way the code will be executed.

You have to reformat the spacing of your code to get out of the forever loop indenting all lines after `while index<=len(pdfs):` by four spaces (four spaces is the Python standard indentation).

You need indentation of lines after the `:` of for, while, if, ... to indicate which lines are part of the for, while, if, ... block.

And if you don't need the indices to index some another list as these one you loop over use always a `for` loop instead of a `while` one as suggested in the answer by *tdelaney*.

Comment: thank you very much, indeed it was the spacing. That would have taken me forever to debug.

Answer (score 0):

you are not increasing the "index" in the while loop,
you should write

```
index = 0
while index<=len(pdfs):
    pdfFileObj = open(str(pdfs[index]), 'rb')
    index=index+1
```

or alternatively you can use the for loop in this way, iterating directly on the pdfs list

```
for pdf in pdfs:
    pdfFileObj = open(str(pdf), 'rb')
```

Comment: thank you, i will give the for loop a go.

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop contains a single line `pdfFileObj = open(str(pdfs[index]), 'rb')` which does not increment `index`. Since `index` never changes, the `while` never terminates.

Python's `for` loop is a better way to process the items of a list. You could rewrite your code to get rid of `index` completely.

```
import glob
import PyPDF2
pdfs=glob.glob("/private/babik/*.pdf")

for pdf in pdfs:
    with open(pdf, 'rb') as pdfFileObj:
        # creating a pdf reader object
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj,strict=False)
        print(pdfReader.numPages)
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(0)
        print(pageObj.extractText())
```

Comment: that is excellent, thanks again. indeed seems like a much better a simpler solution